# How to detect first newline in a string and insert image

Tags: php, regex, html

I am trying to detect first newline and insert image.

Something like this.

Life is good.

Fun is great.

Life is good.
**insert image here(ads)**
Fun is great.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I have a post. Image first then text. If the user does not like the post, they actually ignore it after first newline. That's why i want to place ads after first newline. Thanks

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have try this:  <?php
$string='Life is good.
Fun is great.';
echo preg_replace('/\n/', "\ninserted image here\n", $string);

Comment: Ok, Adi Inbar. Should i remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search `\n`
and replace `\ninsert image here(ads)\n`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hY5dU9)

something like this in php

```
<?php
$string='Life is good.
Fun is great
Life is good
Fun is great
Life is good
Fun is great.';
echo preg_replace('/\n/', "\ninserted image here\n", $string,1);
```

this will replace only the first occurence of `\n`

Comment: Thanks for helping out. The code you explained add images several times. I only want to insert image after first newline. Let me express myself more. I have a post. Image first then text. If the user does not like the post, they actually ignore it after first newline. That's why i want to place ads after first newline. Thanks

Comment: @Olalekan check my updat4e

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple string replace function. No Regex is needed here.

```
<?php

$string = 'Life is good.<br>
<br>
Fun is great.';

$needle = '<br>'; // or \r\n
$replacement = '<br><img src="image.png" alt="Some image">';

$position = strpos($string, $needle);
if ($position !== false) {
    echo substr_replace($string , $replacement , $position, strlen($needle) );
}

?>
```

That should do the trick.